# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" when using custom dialect

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve a collection of data using boundingCoordinates.

Since that requires me using some trigonometric functions (sin, cos, radians, etc) which I know is supported by the database, but not supported in JPA, I tried to create a custom dialect to add support some and also nest the functions, since I can't figure out how to nest function calls in JPA.

This is the dialect I created:

```
public class ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

    public ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect() {
        super();

        registerFunction("eto_radians",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE, "radians(cast(? as double precision ))"));

        registerFunction("cos", new StandardSQLFunction("cos"));

        registerFunction("eto_acos_sin",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE, "acos(sin(?))"));

        registerFunction("eto_sin_radians",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE, "sin(radians(cast(? as double precision)))"));

        registerFunction("eto_cos_radians",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE, "cos(radians(cast(? as double precision)))"));

        registerFunction("eto_radians_distance",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE,
                        "acos(sin(?) * " +
                                "sin(radians(cast(? as double precision))) + " +
                                "cos(?) * " +
                                "cos(radians(cast(? as double precision))) * " +
                                "cos(radians(cast(? as double precision)) - ?)"));
    }
}
```

Somehow it causes my application to not start, with the following issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:40002)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41008)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at package.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:40002)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.__createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:42002)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [package.Application.ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [package.Application.ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.lambda$static$0(StrategySelectorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:216)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer.<init>(TemplateRenderer.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate.<init>(SQLFunctionTemplate.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate.<init>(SQLFunctionTemplate.java:40)
    at package.Application.ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect.<init>(ExtendedPostgreSQL94Dialect.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.__newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.lambda$static$0(StrategySelectorImpl.java:36)
    ... 47 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there something wrong with the function that I'm defining there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I was doing it wrongly.

```
registerFunction("eto_acos_sin",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE, "acos(sin(?))"));
```

Each parameter needs to be numbered/named. Since it was looking for one and found none, it does says it founds nothing. Changed it to this:

```
registerFunction("eto_acos_sin",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(DoubleType.INSTANCE, "acos(sin(?1))"));
```

And then it should work.